# RabbitMQ only processes 50 messages then blocks

Tags: c#, multithreading, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ in .net and I am seeing a weird issue when I drop 100 messages on the queue. It processes approximately 50 messages, then the `Dequeue()` method just hangs. If I restart the service, it processes the remaining items.

**EDIT: It is processing exactly 50% of the queue. When I add 1000 messages, it only processes 500. Even when single threaded**

What am I missing here?

```
    private void InitializeAgent() {
        var agentFactory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
        agentConnection = agentFactory.CreateConnection();
        agentChannel = agentConnection.CreateModel();
        var ok = agentChannel.QueueDeclare(GetType().Name, true, false, false, null);
        consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(agentChannel);
        agentChannel.BasicConsume(GetType().Name, false, consumer);
    }

    public void DequeueMessages() {
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(200, 200);
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 200);
        var ea = consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessWorkInThread, ea);
    }

    public void AgentTask() {
        var instance = factory.GetInstance(threadItem);

        while (true) 
            DequeueMessages();
    }

    private void ProcessWorkInThread(object state) {
         var ea = state as BasicDeliverEventArgs;

         var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);

         var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
         settings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() { DefaultMembersSearchFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public };
         var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TEntity>(message, settings);

         Thread.Sleep(10000) //simulate work
         lock (agentChannel)             
             agentChannel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);            
     }
```

Comment: fairly certain that IModel isn't thread safe. the .net user guide specifically states, IModel should not be shared between threads.

Comment: @user1450877 can I just add a lock around the dequeue & ack?

Comment: have to use one  IModel for thread.

Comment: @ChrisKooken I'm not even sure if that is your problem, but it seems to be a good place to start. Personally if i was going to use your model of processing messages i would dequeue the message and acknowledge it straight after (or turn off acknowledgements) in the DequeueMessages() method, then have the thread do the required work. If there is a problem with the processing of any particular just re-queue it.

Comment: @user1450877 See edits above. Even when I ack instantly, OR remove threading all together, it still only processes 50% of whatever the queue size was when it started up.

Comment: What if you comment out ack and pass true to basic consume to auto ack messages?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Still stops at 500 out of 1000

Comment: So, no threads, auto ack and still stops? Aren't there two consuming agents by chance?

Comment: Please supply the code for the factory and threadItem variables, and the code that actually removes the message from the Queue, if separate.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a .NET client version issue, using `3.4.0`, the following code works as expected.

```
static readonly ConnectionFactory Factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
static readonly IConnection Connection = Factory.CreateConnection();
static QueueingBasicConsumer consumer;
static IModel agentChannel;

static CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    const string queueName = "testQueue";
    agentChannel = Connection.CreateModel();
    agentChannel.QueueDeclare(queueName, true, false, false, null);
    agentChannel.QueueBind(queueName, "testExchange", "");

    consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(agentChannel);
    agentChannel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);

    while (!_tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        DequeueMessages();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
    _tokenSource.Cancel();
}

static void DequeueMessages()
{
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(200, 200);
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(200, 200);
    var ea = consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessWorkInThread, ea);
}

static void ProcessWorkInThread(object state)
{
    var ea = state as BasicDeliverEventArgs;

    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
    {
        DefaultMembersSearchFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public
    };
    var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(message, settings);
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    Thread.Sleep(10000); //simulate work
    lock (agentChannel)
        agentChannel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
}
```